# How to define async fields resolver in GraphqQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I have code to resolve `fields` type in my `Message`.

```
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Message',
  fields: () => ({
    text: { type: GraphQLString },
    comments: new GraphQLList(MessageType),
  }),
});
```

Problem is, that I would like to have `fields` type as async function:

```
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Message',
    fields: async () => {
        await Promise.resolve(r => setTimeout(r, 100)); // <--------------------- PROMISE EXAMPLE
        return  ({
            text: { type: GraphQLString },
            comments: new GraphQLList(MessageType),
        };;
    },
});
```

Problem is, that `fields` type does not accept promise, is there any workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense. Why would you not know the value of `fields` until a promise is fulfilled? What asynchronous thing are you actually doing?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt really make sense, because it is just example. I am fetching some settings from database while I am generating schema.

Comment: You will need to fetch the settings *before* generating the schema, not *while* generating the schema.

Comment: But why? Async/await is normal construction of node js, its really not supported by graphql engine?

Comment: No, `fields` does not accept a promise-returning function, it accepts a fieldconfig-returning function (or a plain fieldconfig object). Why would they support that? It would mean every method of the `GraphQLObjectType` would need to return a promise, since it might have to wait for something, which is a real hassle. Just move the `async`/`await` construction up, and create an `async function getMessageType` that will return a promise for the `MessageType` object.